# WCF JSON web service remove square brackets

Tags: javascript, iphone, wcf, web-services, json

There seems to be a few questions around this, but I can't seem to find a conclusive answer.

I've created a WCF JSON web service that returns perfect JSON and this has been clarified using jsonlint.com.  The web service returns an array (List< myresults>) and this seems to format the JSON with square brackets, like so:

> [{"Image":"http://www.mywebsite/myimage.jpg"}]

Parsing the JSON on the iPhone platform seems to handle the backslashes fine, but it does not play nice with the square brackets - I had to manually remove these using this:

> [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""]; //(for each bracket)

However, I would also like to consume the same JSON in an HTML webpage using jquery and it seems I am faced with the same issue.  Surely there is a more appropriate way to deal with these annoying square brackets?

I'd really appreciate if someone could post an easy way to handle the brackets - either removing them from the web service, or in my javascript code.

Thanks!

If it helps, my Javascript is as follows:

> $.getJSON(urlToMyWebService, function(data) {
>
> ```
>           var items = [];
>
>           $.each(data, function(key, val) {
>               items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
>           });
>
>           $('<ul/>', {
>               'class': 'my-new-list',
>               html: items.join('')
>           }).appendTo('body');
>       });
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets just indicate an array. As you noted, since you're returning an array, it'll have the square brackets.

You'll need to have an array on the JavaScript/Objective C side as well, that's all.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Sometimes it the obvious things that give you most difficulty!

Answer (score 0):

First things first ids in HTML cannot start with numbers, so using `key` as `id` for your `li` is invalid. Second your JSON list contains objects with `Image` property so you probably want this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="li_' + key + '">' + val.Image + '</li>');
});
```

and here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9nUT/2/).